# Heroku process.env.PORT is undefined with PM2 and @babel/register

Tags: node.js, heroku, babeljs, pm2

`process.env.PORT` is coming back undefined when I try to deploy my application to heroku. I am using pm2 and babel as well. I am running the command `"build": "pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js --env production"`. I tried different case of port and came back with no luck. Still returns the 3333 and the app eventually crashes.

Here is my app.js:

```js
import compression from 'compression'
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

import { productsRoute, imagesRoute, testRoute } from './routes'
import { auth } from './middleware'

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || process.env.port || process.env.Port || 3333

// middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(compression())
app.use(auth)

// routes
app.use(`/products`, productsRoute)
app.use(`/images`, imagesRoute)
app.use(`/test`, testRoute)

// start application
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App started on port ${port}`))
```

Here is my server.js

```js
require(`@babel/register`)
require(`./src/app.js`)
```

Here is my pm2 config:

```js
module.exports = {
    apps : [{
        name: `app`,
        script: `./server.js`,
        instances: `max`,
        exec_mode: `cluster`,
        autorestart: true,
        watch: false,
        ignore_watch: [`images`, `node_modules`],
        max_memory_restart: `1G`,
        env: {
            NODE_ENV: `development`,
        },
        env_production: {
            NODE_ENV: `production`,
        },
    }],
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `env`?

Comment: heroku is suppose to override the `process.env.PORT` env. At least that is how it is on all my other projects. @Shaharyar